# Number of forms in js don't reset after page refresh, django and django-dynamic-formsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, formsets

I have a django formset in which a form is dynamically being added and removed using [jquery.formset.js](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js). It keeps track of number of forms that are currently in a formset. But when I refresh the page, the number of forms in a formset doesn't get rest to 1, and due to `min` and `max` number of forms that can be added in the formset, it doesn't allow more forms to be added.

**Initial form:**
[image: Image1]

**With Two forms:**

[image: Image2]

**After Refresh:**

[image: Image3]

I should not have the choice to `remove the form` but I can see it, because the number of forms still is stored as 2. And I can add only 1 more form, because maximum number of forms that can be added is 3.

Please help me handling this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by browser trying to autocomplete all fields in your form to previous values. You can disable it by setting `autocomplete="off"` on hidden fields that are affected by this issue.

Comment: Thank you. It, indeed, was the reason.